# drawing an object on button click WINAPI32

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm pretty new to ***winapi*** and ***c++*** so I'm trying to make drawing project. I created GUI with 3 Radio button to select color, 4 text fields for getting dimensions and a button to draw any object(ex.Rectangle). But I can't figure out a way to draw after clicked button, only way I was able to draw when just I putted down code to ***"WM_PAINT"***

**case WM_CREATE:**

```
    label1 = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Title",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD ,
        200, 10, 60, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    //X,Y,WIDHT,HIGHT
    label2 = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Select color",
        WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
        190, 40, 60, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    HWND radiobutton1, radiobutton2, radiobutton3;
    radiobutton1 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Red",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
        50, 70, 100, 50,
        hwnd, (HMENU)801,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);

    radiobutton2 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Blue",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
        150, 70, 100, 50,
        hwnd, (HMENU)802,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);

    radiobutton3 = CreateWindow(L"BUTTON", L"Green",
        WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | BS_AUTORADIOBUTTON,
        250, 70, 100, 50,
        hwnd, (HMENU)803,
        GetModuleHandle(NULL), 0);


    textbox1 = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
        L"X0", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        50, 120, 50, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    textbox2 = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
        L"Y0", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        110, 120, 50, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    textbox3 = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
        L"X", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        170, 120, 50, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    textbox4 = CreateWindow(L"EDIT",
        L"Y", WS_BORDER | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        230, 120, 50, 20,
        hwnd, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    CreateWindowExA(0, "Button", "Random text", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE |
        WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | BS_TEXT | WS_GROUP |
        WS_TABSTOP, 100, 300, 300, 48, hwnd, (HMENU)811, NULL, 0);
    button = CreateWindow(L"Button",
        L"Print", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER,
        150, 480, 100, 30, hwnd, (HMENU)111, NULL, NULL);

    AddMenus(hwnd);

    break;
```

I tried to do something like this:

**case WM_COMMAND:**

```
    wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
    wmEvent = HIWORD(wParam);
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
    if (wmId == 801)
    {
        if (wmEvent == BN_CLICKED)
        {
            LRESULT chkState = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
            if (chkState == BST_CHECKED)
                qEllipseColor = RGB(255, 0, 0);
        }
        break;
    };
    if (wmId == 802)
    {
        if (wmEvent == BN_CLICKED)
        {
            LRESULT chkState = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
            if (chkState == BST_CHECKED)
                qEllipseColor = RGB(0, 0, 255);
        }
        break;
    };
    if (wmId == 803)
    {
        if (wmEvent == BN_CLICKED)
        {
            LRESULT chkState = SendMessage((HWND)lParam, BM_GETCHECK, 0, 0);
            if (chkState == BST_CHECKED)
                qEllipseColor = RGB(0, 255, 0);
        }
        break;
    };

    switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {


    case 111:{


        HPEN hEllipsePen;
        hEllipsePen = CreatePen(PS_SOLID, 3, qEllipseColor);// qEllipseColor is global which gets its RGB value from radio buttons
        hPenOld = (HPEN)SelectObject(hdc, hEllipsePen);

        Arc(hdc, 100, 100, 500, 250, 0, 0, 0, 0);

        SelectObject(hdc, hPenOld);
        DeleteObject(hEllipsePen);



    }break;
```

Comment: I guess you forgot to `InvalidateRect()`? or you want `GetDC()`?

Comment: `BeginPaint`/`EndPaint` should be used in `WM_PAINT` only, otherwise use `GetDC`/`ReleaseDC`. In `WM_COMMAND` you want to call `InvalidateRect` as suggested by @appleapple

Comment: InvalidateRect() is working for me, great thanks, and i guess I have to use global bool to set when first time to paint

Comment: The way Windows works, you have to remember everything you're meant to draw and redraw it every time you get a `WM_PAINT` message. Or an easier way - keep a memory DC/bitmap that you draw into, and then in `WM_PAINT` you just need to blit that bitmap to the display.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: When the window size changes, you have to recreate the offscreen rendering surface as well, so you have to remember everything you want to draw anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable: No, just create a new memory bitmap and blit the old one into the new one.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: This will destroy all areas, that lie outside the current window size (which may be transient).

Comment: @IInspectable: Obviously you would only resize if the window got bigger. Otherwise, keep the same memory bitmap and blit the visible part. These are beginner-class problems.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: Maybe so, but that's something that's missing from your previous comments, leaving them incomplete.

Comment: @IInspectable: I mean, it was a comment, it was not intended to be a detailed tutorial for the OP on how to write an MSPaint replacement.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: There is a difference between writing up a tutorial, and leaving out a vital piece of information. You didn't write a tutorial, but you left out a vital piece of information. I wasn't complaining, that you didn't write a tutorial. I was pointing out, that your comments were missing a vital piece of information.

Comment: @IInspectable: How to create a memory DC and bitmap is vital too if the user wants to go down that track. They will need to do SOME research no matter how much info is provided via comments.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: While constructing an off-screen render surface is a requirement as well, you specifically contrasted off-screen rendering with keeping the information around to re-create the image. For that to work you have to make a decision when to re-create the backing bitmap. That's a different kind of *vital*.